# How to ignore predefined variables in a template file?

Tags: terraform

I have a automatically generated file with variables. I want to replace these variables. Therefore, I use [`templatefile`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile). It is working unless the file contains a predefined variable like `${__org.name}`, which should not be resolved by Terraform.

I want to ignore predefined variables like `${__org.name}`, but `templatefile` has no feature like this, see [The template provider parses every variable, even those that are undeclared.](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2104).

So I tried to work around it by replaceing the predefined variable with the escaped predefined variable (see [Escape Sequences](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#escape-sequences)), but I get an error:

> Invalid value for "vars" parameter: invalid template variable name "__org.name": must start with a letter, followed
> │ by zero or more letters, digits, and underscores.

**Code**

```
resource "grafana_dashboard" "test" {
  config_json = templatefile("test.json",
    {
      "DS_MYSQL" = grafana_data_source.mysql.uid
      "__org.name" = "$${__org.name}"
  })
}
```

**Generated file**

```json
{
  "__inputs": [
    {
      "name": "DS_MYSQL",
      "label": "MySQL",
      "description": "",
      "type": "datasource",
      "pluginId": "mysql",
      "pluginName": "MySQL"
    }
  ],
  "__elements": {},
  "__requires": [
    {
      "type": "grafana",
      "id": "grafana",
      "name": "Grafana",
      "version": "10.0.3"
    },
    {
      "type": "datasource",
      "id": "mysql",
      "name": "MySQL",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  ],
  "annotations": {
    "list": [
      {
        "builtIn": 1,
        "datasource": {
          "type": "grafana",
          "uid": "-- Grafana --"
        },
        "enable": true,
        "hide": true,
        "iconColor": "rgba(0, 211, 255, 1)",
        "name": "Annotations & Alerts",
        "type": "dashboard"
      }
    ]
  },
  "editable": true,
  "fiscalYearStartMonth": 0,
  "graphTooltip": 0,
  "id": null,
  "links": [],
  "liveNow": false,
  "panels": [],
  "refresh": "",
  "schemaVersion": 38,
  "style": "dark",
  "tags": [],
  "templating": {
    "list": [
      {
        "current": {},
        "datasource": {
          "type": "mysql",
          "uid": "${DS_MYSQL}"
        },
        "definition": "SELECT id AS __value, name AS __text FROM tenant WHERE name = '${__org.name}'",
        "hide": 0,
        "includeAll": false,
        "multi": false,
        "name": "tenant",
        "options": [],
        "query": "SELECT id AS __value, name AS __text FROM tenant WHERE name = '${__org.name}'",
        "refresh": 1,
        "regex": "",
        "skipUrlSync": false,
        "sort": 0,
        "type": "query"
      }
    ]
  },
  "time": {
    "from": "now-6h",
    "to": "now"
  },
  "timepicker": {},
  "timezone": "",
  "title": "DUR test",
  "uid": "c66eafb7-1254-45f3-afdd-a20f1b7cf2a4",
  "version": 3,
  "weekStart": ""
}
```

**Remark**

I think it is a bug, that `templatefile` tries to resolve variables in the file, which are not allowed as an argument, see [templatefile Function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile):

> Variable names must each start with a letter, followed by zero or more letters, digits, or underscores.

However, I need a solution for my problem.

**Research**

- I tried to use [`replace`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/replace) (only for the predefined variable) before `templatefile`, but there is no string version, see [Introduce a template() function that works on string content](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/30616).
- I read [format Function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/format), but there is no support for `${}` syntax.

**Question**

How to ignore predefined variables in a template file?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to generate literal sequences that conflict with Terraform's template syntax then you must use [escape sequences](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#escape-sequences-1) to explain to Terraform which parts should be taken literally and which should be evaluated.

> Backslash sequences are not interpreted as escapes in a heredoc string expression. Instead, the backslash character is interpreted literally.
>
> Heredocs support two special escape sequences that do not use backslashes:
>
> | Sequence | Replacement |
> | --- | --- |
> | `$${` | Literal `${`, without beginning an interpolation sequence. |
> | `%%{` | Literal `%{`, without beginning a template directive sequence. |

For your template in particular, that means you should write `$${__org.name}` instead of just `${__org.name}`. Terraform will then remove the extra `$` and take the remainder of the sequence literally, causing `${__org.name}` to appear directly in the template result.

Comment: Thank you, but the files are generated and I don't want to change it manually. Sure I could write a bash script, which replaces the variables in the file before executing Terraform, but my hope was that I could do it in Terraform, not outside.

Comment: I'm afraid your goal seems to have an unresolvable conflict. If you want to use Terraform's template engine then you need to generate the syntax it's expecting. If you can't generate the syntax it's expecting then you can't use Terraform's template syntax, and will need to find a different solution.

Comment: If you want to use something other than Terraform's own template syntax as input then I think the best answer would be to ignore `templatefile` entirely and implement your own string substitution logic using functions like `regexall` and `replace`. You might find the comments on this GitHub issue useful as a starting point: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/32419

Answer (score 0):

I found some workarounds:

- **Use `replace` instead of `templatefile`**

  You could replace all non predefined variables with [replace Function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/replace).

  ```
  resource "grafana_dashboard" "test" {
    config_json = replace(file("test.json"), "$${DS_MYSQL}", grafana_data_source.mysql.uid)
  }
  ```

  Disadvantages:

  - If you have more than one variable, you have to chain the `replace` function, like

    ```
    replace(replace(file("test.json"), "$${VAR1}", "value1"), "$${VAR2}", "value2")
    ```
- **Escape predefined variables with a script before running Terraform**

  You could escape all predefined variables with [sed](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/sed/).

  ```bash
  $ sed 's/${__org.name}/$${__org.name}/g' generated.json > test.json 
  $ terraform apply
  ```

  Disadvantages:

  - The escaping is not done with Terraform.